# Label refresh automático

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp, label

Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer refresh automaticamente a uma `LABEL` que está numa `Master Page`. Essa `Label` mostra a soma da quantidade dos produtos, e sempre que adiciono um produto ao carrinho a `Label` não faz refresh, apenas faz refresh se eu fizer refresh da próprio página ou se mudar de página. Basicamente queria que a `label` fizesse o refresh da quantidade, assim que o produto fosse adicionado ao carrinho, e não quando se muda de página.

A `Label` está inserida numa `Form View` dentro da `Master`.

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormViewNE" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceNE">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lblNE" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NE") %>' />
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:FormView>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceNE" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$      ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT SUM (Quantidade) AS  NE FROM Carrinho WHERE (IDUtilizador = @IDUtilizador)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:SessionParameter Name="IDUtilizador" SessionField="IDUtilizador" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Poderá ser prestada algum tipo de ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta experimentar substituir a tua 3ª linha de código por esta:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNE" runat="server" Text="<%= Bind("NE") %>" />
```